# Proving that $\mathbb{Z}/6 \cong \mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/3$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

I know how to prove the general case that if $m,n$ are relatively prime, that $\mathbb{Z}/mn \cong \mathbb{Z}/m \times \mathbb{Z}/n$. In this particular case, I want to prove it using the map $\varphi: \mathbb{Z}/6 \to \mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/3$ sending $x \bmod 6 \mapsto (x \bmod 2, x \bmod 3)$. My definition of $\mathbb{Z}/n$ is the set $\{0, 1, \ldots, n-1\}$ with addition defined by $(a,b) \mapsto a + b$ if $a + b < n$ and $a + b - n$ otherwise.

Here is my attempt.

> First we show that the above map $\varphi: \mathbb{Z}/6 \to \mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/3$ is a bijection of sets. Suppose that $\varphi(a) = \varphi(b)$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}/6$. Then $(a \bmod 2, a \bmod 3) = (b \bmod 2, b \bmod 3)$. Therefore, $a \equiv b \bmod 2$ and $a \equiv b \bmod 3$, so there exist $i,j \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a - b = 2i$ and $a - b = 3j$. Therefore, $2i = 3j$. As $3$ is prime and $3 \nmid 2$, we have $3 \mid i$ by Euclid's lemma, so for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have $3k = i$. Therefore,
> $$a - b = 2i = 2(3k) = 6k,$$
> so $6 \mid a - b$, so $a = b$ in $\mathbb{Z}/6$. Therefore, $\varphi$ is injective. As $|\mathbb{Z}/6| = |\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/3|$, this immediately implies surjectivity. It suffices to check that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism. Fix $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}/6$, and denote addition mod $6$ by $*$ and addition in $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/3$ by $\dagger$.
> If $a + b < 6$, we have $a*b = a + b$, and it follows that
> \begin{align*}
> \varphi(a*b) & = \varphi(a + b) = ((a + b) \bmod 2, (a + b) \bmod 3).
> \end{align*}

At this point, I need to break into additional cases: either (i) $a + b < 2$, in which case $a + b < 3$ as well; (ii) $a + b < 3$ but not less than $2$ (i.e., $a + b = 2$); or (iii) $3 \leq a + b < 6$. Then I have to consider the case that $a + b \geq 6$, so $(a+b) \mod 6 = a + b - 6$, and consider the same cases: either (i) $a + b - 6 < 2$; (ii) $a + b - 6 < 3$ but not less than $2$; (iii) $3 \leq a + b - 6 < 6$.

Is this the correct approach to show that this map is an isomorphism?

Comment: Just send a generator to a generator

Comment: \bmod, not \mod

Comment: Note that the actual issue has nothing to do with proving that ${\mathbb Z}_6 \cong {\mathbb Z}_2 \times {\mathbb Z}_3$. It is actually about proving that ${\mathbb Z}_6 \to {\mathbb Z}_2$ (and $\to {\mathbb Z}_3$) is a homomorphism, and the reason that this gets a bit technical is because of the non-standard way of defining ${\mathbb Z}_m$. (It is probably easier to prove that those two maps are homomorphism separately). At some point you'll need to use the fact that $2 \mid 6$ and, for the other one, that $3 \mid 6$.